# How to create sap.m.ComboBox without the strange 'is not a function' error?

Tags: combobox, split, sapui5

I've been playing around with SapUI5 for a while and now I'm facing another issue, which is totally confusing me.

**My goal:** To add a ComboBox to an oTable.

**What I tried:** I decided to do the 'separation of concerns', in order to investigate it better, so I 'extracted' the ComboBox code from the table and am testing it on its own like this:

```
var cbWizardTypes = [
    {
        Code: "0",
        Name: "Name0",
        AdditionalText: "Additional0"
    },
    {
        Code: "1",
        Name: "Name1",
        AdditionalText: "Additional1"
    },
    {
        Code: "2",
        Name: "Name2",
        AdditionalText: "Additional2"
    },
];
// now the template to use when showing the items
var cbWizardTypesTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
    key: "{Code}",
    text: "{Name}",
    additionalText: "{AdditionalText}"
});
// now let's create it and place it
var cbWizardType = new sap.m.ComboBox({
    items: {
        path: cbWizardTypes,
        template: cbWizardTypesTemplate
    },
    showSecondaryValues: true
});
cbWizardType.placeAt(containerID, 'only');
```

Now, this is giving me this error in the console:
[image: Error]

Additionally, I tried not to use a template, just to see what happens

```
var cbWizardType = new sap.m.ComboBox({
    //items: {
    //    path: cbWizardTypes,
    //    template: cbWizardTypesTemplate
    //},
    items: cbWizardTypes,
    showSecondaryValues: true
});
```

In this case, there are no errors in the Chrome Developer Tools - Console. I get a ComboBox with 3 items, but they are all blank.

Now, I will, at least, try to investigate further, although library-preload.js had been minified, so it will be really hard and time-consuming to navigate through all those 'd'-s, 'p'-s, 'j'-s, etc., I guess.

As always, I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the binding path that you assign to the ComboBox. The binding should be a string & not an array. You will have to store the data in a model & bind it then to your control.
The code below should work

```
var cbWizardTypes = [
            {
                Code: "0",
                Name: "Name0",
                AdditionalText: "Additional0"
            },
            {
                Code: "1",
                Name: "Name1",
                AdditionalText: "Additional1"
            },
            {
                Code: "2",
                Name: "Name2",
                AdditionalText: "Additional2"
            },
        ];

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({ items: cbWizardTypes});
        // now the template to use when showing the items
        var cbWizardTypesTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            key: "{Code}",
            text: "{Name}",
            additionalText: "{AdditionalText}"
        });
        // now let's create it and place it
        var cbWizardType = new sap.m.ComboBox({
            items: {
                path: "/items",
                template: cbWizardTypesTemplate
            },
            showSecondaryValues: true
        });

        cbWizardType.setModel(oModel);
        cbWizardType.placeAt(containerID, 'only');
```